# how to set on click listener of recyclerview where list items are heterogenous

Tags: android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, heterogeneous

I have a recyclerview with 2 types of viewholders for showing 2 types of items
i want to implement on click listener on sub itmes in the items
existing solutions shows viewholder class should be implemented as static inside the adapter ,but i have declared them in sepearte file(a tutorial suggested),
So i cant implement onlick listener on the viewholders
my viewholder1 class is

```
    public  class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView label1, label2;
    public ImageView postImage;

    public ViewHolder1(View v) {
        super(v);
        label1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text11);
        label2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text22);
        postImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.dummyImage);
    }


    public TextView getLabel1() {
        return label1;
    }

    public void setLabel1(TextView label1) {
        this.label1 = label1;
    }

    public TextView getLabel2() {
        return label2;
    }

    public void setLabel2(TextView label2) {
        this.label2 = label2;
    }
}
```

viewholder2 is

```
   public  class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView ivExample;

    public ViewHolder2(View v) {
        super(v);
        ivExample = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivExample);
    }

    public ImageView getImageView() {
        return ivExample;
    }

    public void setImageView(ImageView ivExample) {
        this.ivExample = ivExample;
    }
}
```

adapter is

```
public class ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {





    // The items to display in your RecyclerView
    private List<Object> items;

    private final int USER = 0, IMAGE = 1;

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Object> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (items.get(position) instanceof User) {
            return USER;
        } else if (items.get(position) instanceof String) {
            return IMAGE;
        }
        return -1;
    }



    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());

        switch (viewType) {
            case USER:
                View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_viewholder1, viewGroup, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder1(v1);
                break;
            case IMAGE:
                View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_viewholder2, viewGroup, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder2(v2);
                break;
            default:
                View v3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_viewholder2, viewGroup, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder2(v3);
                break;
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
            case USER:
                ViewHolder1 vh1 = (ViewHolder1) viewHolder;
                configureViewHolder1(vh1, position);
                break;
            case IMAGE:
                ViewHolder2 vh2 = (ViewHolder2) viewHolder;
                configureViewHolder2(vh2);
                break;
            default:
                ViewHolder2 vh3 = (ViewHolder2) viewHolder;
                configureViewHolder2(vh3);
                break;
        }

    }
//    private void configureDefaultViewHolder(RecyclerViewSimpleTextViewHolder vh, int position) {
//        vh.getLabel().setText((CharSequence) items.get(position));
//    }
    private void configureViewHolder1(ViewHolder1 vh1, int position) {
        User user = (User) items.get(position);
        if (user != null) {
            vh1.getLabel1().setText(user.getMFName());
            vh1.getLabel2().setText( user.getMName());
            //vh1.postImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.universe);
            Picasso.with(vh1.postImage.getContext())
                    .load(R.drawable.universe)
                    .resize(400,200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
                    .error(R.drawable.error_image)
                    .into(vh1.postImage);
        }
    }
    private void configureViewHolder2(ViewHolder2 vh2) {
       // vh2.getImageView().setImageResource(R.drawable.sample_golden_gate);
        Picasso.with(vh2.getImageView().getContext())
                .load(R.drawable.sample_golden_gate)
                .resize(400,200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel)
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
                .error(R.drawable.error_image)
                .into(vh2.getImageView());
    }

}
```

fragment that uses all

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment  {

    private static final int VERTICAL_ITEM_SPACE = 48;

    Button button;
    RecyclerView rvMixed;
    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        // Lookup the recyclerview in activity layout
        rvMixed = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rvContacts);
        rvMixed.setAdapter(new ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter(getSampleArrayList()));

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
// Control orientation of the items
// also supports LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
// Optionally customize the position you want to default scroll to
        layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0);
// Attach layout manager to the RecyclerView
        rvMixed.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        //adding spacing between recycler view items
       // rvMixed.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(VERTICAL_ITEM_SPACE));




        // That's all!

        return rootView;

    }
    private void bindDataToAdapter() {
        // Bind adapter to recycler view object
        rvMixed = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.rvContacts);
        ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter = new ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter(getSampleArrayList());
        rvMixed.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
    private ArrayList<Object> getSampleArrayList() {
        ArrayList<Object> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new User("Dany Targaryen", "Valyria"));
        items.add(new User("Rob Stark", "Winterfell"));
        items.add("image");
        items.add(new User("Jon Snow", "Castle Black"));
        items.add("image");
        items.add(new User("Tyrion Lanister", "King's Landing"));
        return items;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply pass the click Listener on ComplexRecyclerViewAdapter through its constructor at the time of its initialization. And then you can reuse the same click listener reference for each of the ViewHolder.